# How to join on foreign key in querydsl

Tags: java, sql-server, querydsl

I am new to querydsl and I'm trying to use querydsl in pure java (no hibernate, JPA or anything).

We have a database where the tables are linked through **minimum 3 columns** 
I followed the doc [here](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html) and ended up with my schema duly created.

Here are my pseudo tables :

**Item**

- Corporation (pk) *mmcono*
- Item number (pk) *mmitno*
- Environnement (pk) *mmenv*
- Item description *mmitds*

**Item_warehouse**

- Corporation (fk for Item) *mbcono*
- Item number (fk for Item) *mbitno*
- Environnement (fk for Item) *mbenv*
- Warehouse number *mbwhlo*
- Other properties (not important)

Inside the Item_wharehouse class, I manually added the foreignKey (because it's not defined in the actual db schema)

```
 public final com.querydsl.sql.ForeignKey<QItemWharehouse > _ItemWharehouseFk = createInvForeignKey(Arrays.asList(mbitno, mbcono, mbenv), Arrays.asList("mmitno", "mmcono", "mbenv"));
```

I'm working on the following code in my main class:

```
    SQLTemplates templates = SQLServer2012Templates.builder().printSchema().build();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(templates);

    QItem mm = new QItem ("mm");
    QItemWarehouse mb = new QItemWarehouse("mb");

    JtdsDataSource ds = getDataSource();
    SQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new SQLQueryFactory(configuration, ds);
    String toto = queryFactory.select(mm.mmitno, mm.mmitds)
            .from(mm)
            .join(  ???????????? )
            .where(mb.mbwhlo.eq("122"))
            .fetch()
```

As per doc [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.2/apidocs/com/mysema/query/sql/class-use/ForeignKey.html) I should be able to do something like this : `AbstractSQLQuery.innerJoin(ForeignKey<E> key, RelationalPath<E> entity)`

What I want in the end is to **allow joining table without having to specify manually all the columns required for the join condition**.
As stated before, my model starts with minimum 3 columns in the pk, and it's not uncommon to have 6 or 7 cols in the on clause! It's a lot of typing and very error prone, because you can easily miss one and get duplicate results.

I would like something like `.join(mb._ItemWharehouseFk, ???)` and let querydsl handle little details like generating the on clause for me.

My trouble is that I can't find the second parameter of type `RelationalPath<E> entity` for the join method.

I am doing something wrong ? What do I miss ? Is it even possible to accomplish what I want ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to accomplish what you're looking for. You'll have to specify every join condition.

Comment: thank you @RobertBain, I was affraid it would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups I found the problem : I had it all in the wrong order.

The foreign key was located in the itemWarehouse class.
it should have been named this way :

```
public final com.querydsl.sql.ForeignKey<QItem> _ItemFk = createInvForeignKey(Arrays.asList(mbitno, mbcono, mbenv), Arrays.asList("mmitno", "mmcono", "mbenv"));
```

that means that you just have to reverse the order in the statement this way :

```
SQLTemplates templates = SQLServer2012Templates.builder().printSchema().build();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(templates);

QItem mm = new QItem ("mm");
QItemWarehouse mb = new QItemWarehouse("mb");

JtdsDataSource ds = getDataSource();
SQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new SQLQueryFactory(configuration, ds);
List<Tuple> toto = queryFactory.select(mm.mmitno, mm.mmitds)
        .from(mb)
        .join(mb._ItemFk, mm )
        .where(mb.mbwhlo.eq("122"))
        .fetch()
```

And you get your nice on clause generated. It's just a question of how you construct your relation.

@Enigma, I sincerely hope it will help you for your Friday afternoon. I wouldn't want your boss to be disappointed with you :-)